# Dynamically adjust ItemWidth in WrapPanel

Tags: wpf, wrappanel

I am using WPF MVVM. I have the following code:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}" Height="160" Width="810">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="500" Height ="150" ItemWidth="100" ItemHeight="30"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}"/>
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The code shows that each `CheckBox` has a width of 100. Each line in the `WrapPanel` can contain at most 5 `CheckBox`es due to its size and the `ItemWidth` (500 / 100).

I have multiple `CheckBox` with different widths.

- Most of the check boxes have a width <=100
- One check box has a width equal to 280
- In the future I might have a check box with a width >300 and <=400

I do not want to set the `ItemWidth` explicitly to 280, because most of the items are smaller. Instead, I want each `CheckBox` to take up the space of a multiple of 100 that can display all of its content. If the current line in the `WrapPanel` does not have enough space, then move it to next line.

For the sample widths above I expect this.

- Width <= 100: Occupy 1 item space (Width = 100)
- Width <= 280: Occupy 3 item spaces (Width = 300)
- Width > 300 and <= 400: Occupy 4 item spaces (Width = 400)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

The [`ItemWidth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.itemwidth?view=netcore-3.1#property-value) explicitly defines the width for all items.

> A Double that represents the **uniform width of all items** that are contained within the WrapPanel. The default value is NaN.

Do  **not** set an [`ItemWidth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.itemwidth?view=netcore-3.1#remarks). Then each item occupies its individual size.

> A child element of a WrapPanel may have its width property set explicitly. ItemWidth specifies the size of the layout partition that is reserved by the WrapPanel for the child element. As a result, **ItemWidth takes precedence over an element's own width**.

Now, if you do not *explicitly* define the widths of your items, they are sized to fit their content, but do not align with a multiple of `100`. Scaling items up to a multiple of a defined size automatically is not supported in `WrapPanel`.

If you want to enable this kind of dynamic sizing, you will have to create a custom wrap panel or you can write a custom behavior. I show you an example of the latter, as it is reusable and more flexible. I use the [`Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) NuGet package that contains base classes for that.

```
public class AlignWidthBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty AlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(Alignment), typeof(double), typeof(AlignWidthBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(double.NaN));

   public double Alignment
   {
      get => (double)GetValue(AlignmentProperty);
      set => SetValue(AlignmentProperty, value);
   }

   protected override void OnAttached()
   {
      base.OnAttached();
      AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated += OnLayoutUpdated;
   }

   protected override void OnDetaching()
   {
      base.OnDetaching();
      AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated -= OnLayoutUpdated;
   }

   private void OnLayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      var size = AssociatedObject.ActualWidth;
      var alignment = Alignment;
      var isAligned = size % alignment < 10E-12;

      if (!double.IsNaN(alignment) && !isAligned)
         AssociatedObject.Width = Math.Ceiling(size / alignment) * alignment;
   }
}
```

This behavior is triggered, when the layout of an item changes. It then checks, if the width of the associated item is aligned with the value given by the `Alignment` property and adapts it if not.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}">
      <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <local:AlignWidthBehavior Alignment="100"/>
      </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}"/>
   </CheckBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

You have to attach the behavior in XAML as shown above and set the `Alignment` to your desired value and do not forget to remove the `ItemWidth` property from `WrapPanel`.